# What is the best way to validate if a record was inserted successfully?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is the best way to validate if a record was inserted successfully?

I'm using PDO Statements.

This:

```
/*******************
Update user picture
********************/
function updateuserpicture($userid, $filename) {
    include ("./businesslogic/dbconnection/cfg.php");
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$server.';dbname='.$db,$db_user,$db_password);
        $sql = $db->prepare("Update usersdata set userpicture=:filename where userid=:userid");
        $sql->bindParam(':filename',$filename);
        $sql->bindParam(':userid',$userid);
        $sql->execute();
        $sqlresult = $sql->rowCount();
        $db = null;
        return $sqlresult; //Then validate if result is greater than 0.
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

or this:

```
/*******************
Update user picture
********************/
function updateuserpicture($userid, $filename) {
    include ("./businesslogic/dbconnection/cfg.php");
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$server.';dbname='.$db,$db_user,$db_password);
        $sql = $db->prepare("Update usersdata set userpicture=:filename where userid=:userid");
        $sql->bindParam(':filename',$filename);
        $sql->bindParam(':userid',$userid);
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            $db = null;
            return TRUE; 
        } else {
            $db = null;
            return FALSE;
        } //Then validate if result is TRUE or FALSE.
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Both ways works fine but im not sure what is the best, can you please help me?

Comment: fyi, in the second example, you are executing the statement twice

Comment: Thanks r3wt and deceze, the code was updated.

Comment: what happens if the userid doesn't exist?

Comment: I change my code, in the catch i add `return FALSE`. If the userid don't exists the function will be return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. PDO won't actually throw exceptions unless you tell it to. So your `try..catch` is entirely superfluous and will never do anything.
2. If the statement was executed without error, that means the data was inserted/updated successfully. No need to count rows, unless you are interested in the specific details of how many rows were altered (which is a different topic than *"is the data in my database now?"*).

Given this, I'd recommend to set PDO to throw exceptions in case of errors and not do any further explicit checking:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db", $db_user, $db_password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET userpicture = :filename WHERE userid = :userid');
$sql->bindParam(':filename', $filename);
$sql->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
$sql->execute();
```

This may still mean that the statement did nothing if the user id didn't exist. This would point to a deeper bug in your app, it's questionable if the PDO code should care about it specifically.

Comment: You mean remove the `try-catch` or only add: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);?

Comment: @Juan Both. You *need* to add `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, otherwise `try..catch` is pointless in the first place. But secondly, you do not typically want to `catch` exceptions. Exceptions are errors in exceptional circumstances. Ideally you never ever see an exception. If an exception is thrown, that means something is seriously wrong. You shouldn't just treat it like *"oh well, whatever, let's move on"*. Let it bubble up and crash the application; or at least `catch` it somewhere further up where catching it may make more sense.

Comment: Thank you veru much @deceze, one more question, is valid to use `try-catch` and in the `catch` section add a `return FALSE` or you recommend avoid to use `try-catch`?

Comment: @Juan Again: if an exception is ever thrown by PDO, that means something is **seriously wrong**. Like, *your database is down* kind of wrong. Or *your query has a terminal bug* kind of wrong. What good does it do to `return false` in that case? You need to kill your application and fix whatever you need to fix in that case. So *not catching* the exception is the only right thing to do.